What to give path in firefox Driver config file in Jmeter as I am using Macos
Here is screen shot as I am using macos I am unable to find setup steps . I have already installed firefox in my system. So please help me .
Due to which when I run facing this error :
    2024-10-06 23:13:43,327 ERROR o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Error calling threadStarted
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Actual executable Unable to find executable for: /Applications/jmeter/bin/path to driver.exe of the relevant browser
    at org.openqa.selenium.internal.Require$StateChecker.nonNull(Require.java:314) ~[selenium-api-4.13.0.jar:?]

What to give "Path to driver" section as I am using Macos

why down vote , there was no mac related solution which i found .


You need to download the relevant Geckodriver (aarch64 if you're using Apple M1/M2/whatever or x86_64 if you're using Intel processor)
Once you unpack the archive you will see the geckodriver file there. Copy it to any convenient place.

If you want to use JMeter's "bin" folder for this you will need to provide the following path:
/Applications/jmeter/bin/geckodriver

More information: How to Use JMeter for Selenium WebDriver Testing
